# What's the dimensionality of the output space in Tensorflow's docs?

Tags: tensorflow

I've been going through the docs recently and in many different functions like *[tf.layers.dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense)* or the *[tf.nn.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d)*, I came across with the arguments *units* and *filters* respectively and I can't understand the point of them. Can someone clearly describe the meaning of

> dimensionality of the output space

in the above cases or maybe more general terms? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from my opinion:

`units` in `tf.layers.dense`:

- means that how many output nodes of dense layer should be returned.
- Because the fully connected layer(dense layer) should consist of `input` and `output`.
- Then , the mean of `dimensionality of the output space` could be translated to the **number of ouput nodes**.
- if the **units = 1** , it means **all the input nodes connected to one output nodes**
- in inception v3 or other classifier model, we could found the **units** of dense layer always be the classifier number.

`filters` in `tf.nn.conv2d`:

- like the state in api doc :

  > filter: A Tensor. Must have the same type as input. A 4-D tensor of shape [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]
- maybe the confused point is out_channels

  > for `out_channels` , I try to understand it as how many filters we want to scan the input tensors.
- so `out_channels` is regarded as the number of kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand the meaning of filters in the tf.nn.conv2d

Comment: ：）. It was really hard to understand is at once.  For `filters`, in some articles , it said **"A filter is represented by a vector of weights with which we convolve the input. "**. And for `tf.nn.conv2d` ,  the shape of `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]` which means size , input , output just like the dense layer. And for dense layer , the input `x` would be used as  `y = x * k + b`, and for filers `[filter_height, filter_width]` would be used as convolutional which is a 2-D parameters